# VS Code java won't change to standard mode

Tags: java, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, virtual

When I click the rocket ship icon to change to standard mode the following message comes up, "command 'java.runtimevalidation.open' already exists". I've tried cleaning the language server workspace and changing it in settings by changing java server launch mode to standard which also doesn't work. My code runs but the debugger doesn't work. [My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1mDV.png)

Comment: Does [reset VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/setup/setup-overview#_how-can-i-do-a-clean-uninstall-of-vs-code) help?

Comment: @MollyWang-MSFT yeah i did, didnt work

Comment: Does this question happen in every java project?

Comment: @MollyWang-MSFT yeah

Comment: This question can't be reproduced in my project, you may ask in [github/vscode-java](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues) for more help.